# Emulate Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to emulate the Nexus 7, but I can't figure out what values to use.
Skin: Built-in or custom resolution? What hardware properties should I use?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you're running the latest version of the plugin (20) then when you're creating your new device there is an option within the Skin drop-down list for "WXGA800-7in"

```
Abstract LCD Densit: 213
Hardware Back/Home keys: no
Keyboard lid support: no
Max VM Heap size: 48
Device ram: 1024
```

Comment: I get "Failed to allocate memory: 8. This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way." error message. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: @StenaviN Changing the target API from **Android 4.1** to **Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 16** solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Ben, It helps! I'm shocked! You are genius! Thank you!

Comment: @StenaviN I have the same problem here, but your suggested change to Google APIs doesn't work :| Any ideas?

Comment: Didn't work for me either. I changed the resolution to 800x1280 (manually) and it works now.

Comment: Google recommends also enabling graphics acceleration in the emulator:

"To test your application on an emulator that represents the Nexus 7 tablet device, you can create an AVD with the new WXGA800-7in skin. For best performance, make sure to enable graphics acceleration in the emulator configuration."

http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/platforms.html

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of plugin (21.1.0), You can emulate the Nexus 7 specifically.

When creating a new device in the AVD manager, You can select the

> "Nexus 7(7.27",800 x 1280: tvdpi)"

option in the Device dropdown.

This creates Nexus 7 emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can't emulate the Nexus 7 specifically, but if you target API level 16 and set the resolution to 800x1280, you'll have an environment pretty similar to it.

Comment: I want to emulate it to view my layout on the device. Should I set some dpi value somewhere, and to what? Or is that not necessary? I mean, I want to show a 800x1280 resolution in a 7" screen.

Comment: @Niek No, you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Is actual Nexus 7 tablet good to go as an 10 inch tablet from a developer's point of view? Will it accept the same settings as a 10 inch tablet, namely: -sw720dp ?  I just wonder if I buy a Nexus 7, won't I still have to buy a 10 inch tablet?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that after selecting WXGA800-7in I then need to delete the "Device ram size" option (otherwise I get the "Failed to allocate memory: 8" error mentioned) and then add the "GPU emulation" option with value yes to remove the "Skipped xx frames!" choreographer messages.